# What is the difference between Sleep vs Wait in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-sleep

In one of my recent interviews I was asked about Sleep vs Wait. If I understand correctly then Sleep belongs to Thread and Wait is related to Task. So, I explained separately both of them not the comparison. But interviewer was not happy. He said there are couple of things can be done by both so comparison is needed to decide which is better to use in which scenario. Also, he was expecting how these two behave when lock is acquired. In short after our discussion I have got 2 basic questions:

1. Can we really compare Sleep and Wait in the context of .Net? If yes then what would be the points?
2. Suppose they already have acquired some lock and then we Sleep or Wait then what will happen to Lock, will it be released? (Not sure about this scenario whether it is practical or not)

The above statement might be confusing because I am confused about what he said/expecting but I tried to writ whatever we discussed. So, I would appreciate if anyone shares their knowledge on above confusing situation.

Comment: Please elaborate on "Wait"? What Wait? Did you mean `Task.Delay()`?

Comment: 1. They are two different things: sleeping means just blocking and waking up after a defined amount of time, waiting means waiting on another object or lock. 2. No, why should it? Tasks and threads can do both sleeping and waiting, but they behave differently: tasks return control to the caller, threads do not.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen not the `Task.Delay()`. I assume here wait is `Task.Wait()`. Like I mentioned in post even I am not sure what is what. I am just guessing based on my knowledge.

Comment: Those are two separate things. `Sleep` blocks a thread for a certain time. Task.Wait waits until the task is finished and yes, it also blocks the current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we really compare Sleep and Wait in the context of .Net? If yes then what would be the points?

Yes. These are seemingly similar mechanisms but they differ significantly and are meant to be use for different purposes. Main differences are:

- `Task.Wait()` is called on a Task (so basically on an object) - `Thread.Sleep()` is called on a specific thread.
- `Task.Wait()` is used to await task result with set timeout. If the task does not finish within specified time span, execution is resumed and method returns `false`. - `Thread.Sleep()` is used to freeze thread execution (to synchronize its activities with other threads). If it is interrupted, an exception is raised and if it is ignored, the thread gets stopped.
- Both mechanisms can be interrupted. `Thread.Sleep()` can be awaken either by `Thread.Interrupt()` or `Thread.Abort()` - `Task.Wait()` can be interrupted by Task cancellation or its exception.

**Sources:**

[Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/pausing-and-resuming-threads)

[Task.Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-6.0)

[Thread.Interrupt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.interrupt?view=net-6.0)

Comment: _"When executing Task.Wait() the lock will be released"_ -  an you please elaborate and show some examples/docs?

Comment: As you've mentioned it, it occurred to that it does not make sense at all. I misunderstood another post while preparing the answer. At no point in the docs that I've linked to is there such information. I've edited the answer now.

Comment: @EmilKucharczyk what about locks. Will lock be released when we call Wait or Sleep?

Comment: Neither Wait() nor Sleep() will cause a lock to be released.